# ¿Es despectivo el uso de la palabra "individuo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Es despectivo decir "individuo". Por ejemplo:

> ¿Por qué estás hablando con ese individuo?

Comment: Por lo menos en cuba, en ese contexto si es despectivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usarlo de esa manera es un poco irónico. Se usa en un contexto relajado y entre amigos. Usualmente "individuo" se pronuncia haciendo énfasis en la palabra. Es despectivo, si el "individuo" es una persona que ambos conocen, aún cuando no se conozcan personalmente, y la historia entre el "individuo" y cualquiera de los participantes es negativa. Depende mucho del tono en el que la palabra es pronunciada. El problema con la palabra es que al ser muy formal añade un toque diferente al referirse a otra persona.

> Están dos personas hablando, se despiden y una de ellas se acerca a otra, esta otra persona le dice:
>   ¿Qué hacías hablando con ese individuo?

Esto puede significar varias cosas:

- Que la segunda persona está celosa del "individuo".
- Que el "individuo" puede tener una historia pasada, un ex, un pretendiente etcétera (Siguen siendo celos).
- Que la persona que estaba habalndo con el individuo y el individuo no se caen bien o tienen problemas.

> Pues nada, él me habló y sólo lo saludé.
>
> ¿Qué te importa?
>
> Pues ya arreglamos todo.

Estas son posibles respuestas.

Answer (score 4):

No siempre. Como indica la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=evJG6UwjYDXX2RG5pwPM) su uso es coloquial, pero no siempre es despectivo.

Como muestra, un par de ejemplos de [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/individuo).

> Lo malo de las grandes urbes es que anulan al individuo.
>
> Los miembros de esa especie se agrupan en pequeñas colectividades de unos diez o doce individuos.

Podrías incluso oír:

> La policía busca a un individuo de raza blanca, de metro ochenta de altura...

en la televisión, y no tendría connotaciones despectivas. En tu ejemplo, es más bien *el tono* del hablante lo que pone esa connotacion despectiva.